# Animate in/out table view cell through UI action

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view whose cells contain a UISwitch. For one of them, when the switch is turned on, I'd like to show an additional row in the table view. I'm doing this now by setting conditionals in my `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods and calling `reloadData` in the switch's event handler. This works fine. However, I'd like to animate the table cell in or out, and I can't figure out how to work this into the existing table view insert/remove animation API.

The code I have:

```
- (IBAction)didToggleContractProperties:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *toggle = (UISwitch *)sender;
    switch (toggle.tag) {
        case 100:        // Packaging requested
            self.contract.isPackingRequired = toggle.on;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 101:        // On-campus pickup
            self.contract.isOnCampus = toggle.on;
            break;
        case 102:        // Insurance requested
            self.contract.isInsuranceRequested = toggle.on;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0) {
        if (self.contract.isPackingRequired)
            return 4;
        else
            return 3;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you might do it for the `isPackRequired` switch, for example:

```
- (IBAction)didToggleContractProperties:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *toggle = (UISwitch *)sender;
    switch (toggle.tag) {
        case 100:        // Packaging requested
            if (self.contract.isPackingRequired != toggle.on)
            {
                self.contract.isPackingRequired = toggle.on;
                if (toggle.on)
                {
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
                }
            }
            break;
        case 101:        // On-campus pickup
            ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Obviously, change the `row` and `section` to be the appropriate values for the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `dleeteRowsAtIndexPaths` calls, to reflect where you want this row inserted/deleted.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most complete answer. I had tried `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`, but I forgot the corresponding `delete` method and the app was crashing because the number of rows was inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The way to add table cells animated is this

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

where tableView is your table view, and indexPaths is a mutable array containing the index paths for the new rows.

Answer (score 0):

When your switch gets on then just add up your array with addition items or condition in your case and then just call this method to intended your section. This will give in/out effect to display less and more items to tableview.

```
[mytv reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```